# How to pass a parameter into addEventListener("click", myFunction)?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

When adding the eventlistener ("click", myFunction) how can I pass in a parameter to myFunction without invoking it? Like... ("click", myFunction(arrayOne)).
The button is triggering a function that uses arrays. I want the function to use a specific array based on a specific button.

```
   var btnOne = document.getElementById("btnOne);
   btnOne.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Comment: See [`<Function>.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: `btnOne.addEventListener('click', ()=>myFunction('hi'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrow function to do it. It'll help you by not creating a new lexical scope, so no need to worry about mishandling `this`.

```
var btnOne = document.getElementById("btnOne");
btnOne.addEventListener("click", () => { myFunction(arg1, arg2...) });
```

Comment: What do you mean by mishandling `this`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var btnOne = document.getElementById("btnOne);
btnOne.addEventListener("click", () => myFunction(params));
```